# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable from Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, module

I am trying to use a module located in the same directory as the script I am running and I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

This was working before, but I did some modifications to the sys.path list since I wanted to call modules from other directories, and from that point it stopped working.

This is my folder's structure:

```
Neural_Network/
  split_data.py
  test.ipynb
```

I get the error executing test.ipynb:

```
import split_data
import os

print(split_data.__file__)
trainset, testset, valset = split_data.split_data_func(os.path('data'))
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4936/633432209.py in <module>
      4 
      5 print(split_data.__file__)
----> 6 trainset, testset, valset = split_data.split_data_func(os.path('data'))
      7 
      8 """"

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

`print(split_data.__file__)` is giving the right path to the module.

The module split_data.py has a single function:

```
import math
import os
import random
def split_data_func(path):
...
  return trainset, testset, valset
```

This was working before and I don't know what could have happened.

In the sys.path I have the path to Neural_Network/ directory.

**UPDATE**

I was looking the error regarding the split_data module and the error was with the os module, I just changed to:

```
trainset, testset, valset = split_data.split_data_func(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'dataset_days'))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.path` is a module which contains functions. Since it's a module, you can't use it as a function. Did you mean `pathlib.Path` instead of `os.path`? Or did you mean to call one of the functions within, like `os.path.join('data', split_data.__file__)`?

The error is unrelated to the code being  run in a notebook, it's a common python error.